# How to Parse Gradle task arguments

Tags: gradle, groovy, arguments, task

I have a task that needs to accept any arguments that starts with a specific prefix.
I have this :

```
def props = project.properties.findAll ({k,v -> k.startsWith("test_")}).collectEntries ({k,v -> [k - "test_", v]})
task name(){
doLast{
 props.each {k,v -> project.ext.setProperty(k,v)}

}
}
```

I want to run this in command line ;

```
./gradlew name -Ptest_foo=bar.
```

I am using the ‘test_foo’ value to override a default value in my code however it s not working as expected.It s returning the default value and does not take the command line argument into consideration.
Please any help or advice will be highly appreciated.
Note : I am pretty new to Gradle and groovy.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "*It s returning the default value and does not take the command line argument into consideration*"?  The following works as I'd expect:

```
def props = project.properties.findAll { k, v -> k.startsWith("test_") }
    .collectEntries { k, v -> [k - "test_", v] }

tasks.register("test") {
    doLast {
        props.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Then you can get the expected output:

```
➜ gradle test -Ptest_foo=yay -Ptest_bar=baz

> Task :test
foo=yay
bar=baz
```

Where is the issue you are seeing?  Are these supposed to be passed to something else omitted from the question?

#### Update

Ok, so given this test class in `src/main/java/test`:

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("tim", "nope"));
    }
}
```

Which prints the value of the system property "tim" if it exists (or "nope" if it's missing)

We can then use this build script:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "application"
}

def props = project.properties.findAll { k, v -> k.startsWith("test_") }
    .collectEntries { k, v -> [k - "test_", v] }

mainClassName = "test.Main"

tasks.withType(JavaExec).named("run").configure { t ->
    props.each { k, v ->
        t.systemProperty k, v
    }
}
```

To configure the default `run` task that the `application` plugin creates

Then when we go with no property, we get:

```
➜ gradle run               

> Task :run
nope

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 630ms
```

And when we set a property, it's seen by the class:

```
➜ gradle run -Ptest_tim=yay

> Task :run
yay

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 552ms
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes the value is passed to a class in my java code. the default value is the value of test_foo in the java-code.

Comment: So via a JavaExec task?

Comment: yes, the goal is to be be able to override test arguments that already exist in the code. in the javacode I have String value = System.getProperty("test_foo") else value = "defaultvalue". And yes via JavaExec task. thank you so much for helping

Comment: @Taouscreations no worries...  Hopefully my updated answer helps 